# thread member function and mex file crash with std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, c++11, mex

I have a class for doing some calculation (multi-threaded), and I wrap it with Matlab's mex file (in Linux, compiled with gcc 4.9), that is, the mex has a variable which is an instance of that class. In order to monitor the calculation, the class has two variables: `_did_fit_finish` (bool), so I know to stop monitoring when the calculation ends, and `_info_str` which is updated by another member function. This is how the monitoring function looks like (`g_info_print_interval` is a const global):

```
template <typename T_Float>
void GmmFit<T_Float>::print_timing(void) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); // let the gmm-fit start running
    while ( !_did_fit_finish ) {
        std::cout << _info_str.append("\n");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(g_info_print_interval));
    }
}
```

The problem is that on exiting, the mex file causes matlab to crash with this message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

The crash happens on the mex exit, so I cannot try-catch it in the mex code. 
One question is, when such exception is thrown other than a failed `new` operator? My code does not try to allocate huge amount of memory (at least not in the described use case)

What I know so far:

1. It happens only in "release" mode, that is if I compile with `mex -g` it runs ok. So I cannot debug with gdb.
2. It happens in a specific use case: a specific input to the mex function, and calling the mex from a *specific point in the the matlab script which uses the mex file* - this is really weird, since if I just call the mex without using the script (and the exact same input of course), it does not crash.

   3. If I disable the monitoring (the `MEX_GMM_VERBOSE` below) , it does not crash.

This is the relevant code block in the mex file:

```
 GmmFit<T_Float> gmmFit;
 std::thread readTiming;
 try {
     gmmFit.init(inMat.dimX, inMat.dimY, cfg, initType);
     #ifdef MEX_GMM_VERBOSE
     printf("number of available threads (as returned from std::thread::hardware_concurrency()): %d\n", gmmFit.num_available_threads);
     std::thread readTiming = std::thread(&GmmFit<T_Float>::print_timing, &gmmFit);
     #endif
     model = gmmFit.fit(inMat, initGuess);
     #ifdef MEX_GMM_VERBOSE
     readTiming.detach();
     #endif
  }
catch (...) {
    readTiming.detach();
    mexErrMsgTxt("Unknown exception caught");
}
```

This is the stack from matlab's crash mesaage:

```
Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00002aaaad1d4925                                   /lib64/libc.so.6+00207141 gsignal+00000053
[  1] 0x00002aaaad1d6105                                   /lib64/libc.so.6+00213253 abort+00000373
[  2] 0x00002aab417c7be5 /u/itamark/speech-magneton/research/utils/gmmFit/src/mex/mexGmmFit.mexa64+00457701
[  3] 0x00002aab41780f26 /u/itamark/speech-magneton/research/utils/gmmFit/src/mex/mexGmmFit.mexa64+00167718
[  4] 0x00002aab41780f71 /u/itamark/speech-magneton/research/utils/gmmFit/src/mex/mexGmmFit.mexa64+00167793
[  5] 0x00002aab417b9900 /u/itamark/speech-magneton/research/utils/gmmFit/src/mex/mexGmmFit.mexa64+00399616
[  6] 0x00002aaaacf8c9d1                             /lib64/libpthread.so.0+00031185
[  7] 0x00002aaaad28ab6d                                   /lib64/libc.so.6+00953197 clone+00000109
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please explain why make the thread detached, rather than joined ? 
without definition of `MEX_GMM_VERBOSE`, the thread is not created at all, thus, the problem is something about the thread runnable. 
After mex exit, the concerning objects are destroyed, but, the created timing thread may still be running, and try to access/write the destroyed objects (`_info_str`, `_did_fit_finish`). 
And, since the referenced variables like `_info_str` and `_did_fit_finish` are also updated by other threads, they should be protected by a lock. 
 Thus, I suggest you to make the timing thread joined, and protect `_info_str` and `_did_fit_finish` with locks.

Comment: the reason is that if the sampling period is e.g 30 seconds, I do not want to wait these extra 30 seconds before exiting (in the worst case) after the calculation is over.

Comment: regarding the lock, changing the variable was not intended - these variables should only be updated by the main thread. I will fix it.

Comment: Ok, it seems that using `join` avoids the crash (thanks!) - but there must be a solution to the use case of detaching a thread which have access to potentially destroyed resources - I'm sure it's a common scenario, no?